# Spring annotations static content - access restriction (controllers only)

Tags: pattern-matching, spring-boot, spring-annotations, restrictions, static-content

I am using Spring annotations with boot.

Currently, i'm handling static content in the following way:

```
@RequestMapping("/{path:[^\\.]*}")
public String getResourceFile(@PathVariable("path") String path) {
  return path + ".html";
}
```

That way, if one access mysite.com/login, he will get login.html file.

Note: I do know one can configure spring to handle static content rather than implement a controller method, however I was unable to achieve the above result, no matter the configuration.

Anyhow, my current problem is I don't want users to actually reach the .html files.
That is, I want the above to still work, AND any user trying to reach *.html file
will get an error (not found).

I thought about implementing a controller method for *.html files (regex pattern matching), However they also trigger when I try to forward the url from the controller file, as mentioned above.

How can I achieve this then?

## EDIT

Also, I would love to know how I can redirect from a controller, to a not-controller (even if it matches). That way, I'll be able to create a controller for all paths.
Note currently, I only handle one url 'level';
That is, the url mysite.com/data/login will not match. And I can't use **, since it will then be recursive. That is, i'm looking for something like the following:

```
@RequestMapping("/**")
public String getResource(HttpServletRequest request) {
  String path = request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);

  // Following is WRONG.
  // It will call this function over and over again, resulting
  // in path.html.html.html ..
  return path + ".html"; // WRONG
}
```